# IOError: [Errno 4] Interrupted function call PythonService.exe

Tags: python-2.7, ioerror

I am running a python script as windows background service with the help of pywin32 API that provides PythonService.exe which run my script.

It continuously handles requests and responds back. Once I did not get response hence I checked weather the service is stopped ? I found the service is stopped and the system event log I found is :

```
**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32\lib\win32serviceutil.py", line 806, in SvcRun
    self.SvcDoRun()
  File "\..\..\MyServices.py", line 128, in SvcDoRun
    self.main()
  File "\..\..\MyServices.py", line 141, in main
    execfile('C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\MyPackage\main.py')
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\MyPackage\main.py", line 26, in <module>
    time.sleep(1)
IOError: (4, 'Interrupted function call') 
%2: %3**
```

I went through some of the blogs and found that this error occurs when a SIGBREAK signal is provided to process, but I am not able to reproduce the same error as myscript is running in service.

Does anyone knows the cause of this ERROR and how can I reproduce it in service ??

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the possible ways to send the signals to PythonService.exe but was not able to reproduce it. I tried kill,log off and other methods to generate the error.

But for none of them I succeed, finally I found the way to reproduce it by **shutting down** the machine. It's very rare scenario when your program is stuck in sleep and **shutdown** occurs. Hence to reproduce the same one needs to increase the sleep time and then run service.

Actually my Cloud VM might have went in maintenance at that time.